# How do I change color of the TEXT EDIT control when I am entering text and change the color again after I am done typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I change color of the TEXT EDIT control when I am entering text and change the color again after I am done typing.

I need black color text on typing after typing if i go to next edit text the previous one should be in white color.and one more thing i placed all edittexts in list view.How do i get?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Implement textwatcher for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can create a focus changed listener as a global variable.

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener listener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(hasFocus ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        };
```

Now set that listener to the edittext you create on your listview.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
```

So when you are in the edittext, its color will be black and when you leave the edittext the color will be changed to white and the next edittext focused will become black.

Answer (score 1):

**simple and effective solution**

Create inside **`res/color`** folder `textcolorselector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFF"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000"/>
    <item android:color="#000"/>
</selector>
```

now in editext.

```
  <EditText

        android:textColor="@color/textcolorselector">

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
etEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                etEmail.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                etEmail.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.defaultColor));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher

Example

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        { 
           //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        { 
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```